# Crusty white armpit stain that can't be removed by washing

Tags: everyday-chemistry, cleaning

[image: my overexposed stain]

Some of my t-shirts (the ones that are 100% cotton) started developing this strange armpit stain:

- it makes the fabric feel brittle and crusty around it;
- it can't be washed off with water and detergent;
- it can't be scrapped off easily.

Now here's some information about the environment my clothes *live* in:

- our water is moderately hard (60-120 ppm);
- I use a deodorant that has the following ingredients:

[image: ingredients found in my deodorant]

- I sweat a lot and our climate is quite dry.

---

I was thinking I'm dealing with a boring calcium carbonate deposit, but I don't really want to start drowning all my stained shirts in vinegar without first knowing what I'm dealing with. What do you guys think it is and how would you get rid of it?

Comment: I don't suspect it would be calcium carbonate in your armpits if it isn't everywhere else. Salt would come out, but that would have been my first guess. Maybe it's aluminum salts (or something else) from the antiperspirant. I've always noticed it to be pretty hydrophobic. Does it make your fingers feel strange if they're wet? I don't know how to describe the feeling. Kind of dry but covered in sort of a pasty substance.

Comment: @sendersreagent if feels pretty much the same, maybe less crusty. Do you know anything that dissolves aluminium salts so we can test this out?